# Single process blocking queue

Tags: java, queue, message-queue, priority-queue

I am writing an application that communicates with hardware. While the application can receive and process multiple requests simultaneously in parallel, the hardware cannot!

The hardware requires these parallel requests to basically be organised into a linear request chain each one executed one after the other.

I also have a requirement to be able to prioritise requests given that some of are background processes with no urgency and some are live and need to be jumped to the front of the queue for immediate processing.

I don't have much experience with queues however I would be surprised if such a library didn't already exist.

Comment: What is the problem with coding one? And, acquire lock on the single process/object that is in the front of the queue which you're taking out to be served by the hardware.

Comment: @shekhar suman Absolutely nothing. But I don't want to re-invent the wheel before exploring what is already exists!

Comment: @tarka- I meant to say concurrent API's are there to help you to allow one-by-one access to hardware resource. See, `Java Concurrent API`,and you are already talking about using Priority Queue as a queue for that `lock-acquiring` process.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

see https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html

I would advise using wrapper for your requests that has priority value specifically for this queue. For instance, you can use Long as that value, where you calculate

```
value = timestamp % N * priorityLevel
```

N is dependent on how long it takes you to process your events

priorityLevel is value where lower means more urgent (bigger than zero)

---

**EDIT**: after specification in comments

it seems like you need to create instance of 
[ThreadPoolExecutor](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ThreadPoolExecutor.html)
and pass it your own queue which would be instance of [PriorityBlockingQueue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html). Task you put into this pool need to implement [Comparable](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html) that will order them by their execution priority.

See bit [old reference](http://binkley.blogspot.fr/2009/04/jumping-work-queue-in-executor.html), but as inspiration should be sufficient.

---

**EDIT**: suggested priority function is dangerous for smaller N, now looking at numbers, long can be multiplied a lot before overflow would happen, so leaving modulo out will do little and less, especially if you have only two priority levels (sorry about mystification)

---

**EDIT**: implementation of suggested solution

```
import java.util.concurrent.PriorityBlockingQueue;
import java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class QTest {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        //create executor with exactly one thread (first four arguments) that is
        //using priority queue to store tasks (it takes care of sorting by priority)
        ThreadPoolExecutor executor = new ThreadPoolExecutor(1, 1, 0, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, new PriorityBlockingQueue());
        executor.execute(new EventWrapper(1, "A"));
        executor.execute(new EventWrapper(2, "B"));
        executor.execute(new EventWrapper(1, "C"));
        executor.execute(new EventWrapper(3, "D"));
        executor.execute(new EventWrapper(1, "E"));
        //just to have it terminated once test is done
        executor.shutdown();
    }
}

//in this wrapper should be loaded anything you want to have executed
class EventWrapper implements Comparable<EventWrapper>, Runnable{
    public final long priority;
    //name just to recognize what is being executed
    public final String name;
    public EventWrapper(int priority, String name){
        //priority function out of current time, can be obviously inserted from elsewhere
        this.priority = priority*System.currentTimeMillis();
        this.name = name;
    }

    @Override
    public int compareTo(EventWrapper that) {
        //lower priority first
        if(this.priority==that.priority)return 0;
        return this.priority>that.priority?1:-1;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        System.out.println("Executing task "+name+" with priority "+priority);
        //sleep to rule out speed of insertion in executor
        try {Thread.sleep(1000);
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) {}
    }
}
```

Result for created tasks is

```
Executing task A with priority 1433276819484
Executing task C with priority 1433276819485
Executing task E with priority 1433276819485
Executing task B with priority 2866553638970
Executing task D with priority 4299830458455
```

Comment: OP actually already knows about the priority queue, he/she is asking about library/methods to how to get the work done. I am not sure whether your answer serves his/her purpose...

Comment: @shekharsuman Where does the OP indicate that he is familiar with `PriorityQueue`?

Comment: @Kayaman-Check that the question is tagged with this `Priority-Queue`. It means OP already knows about the same.

Comment: From tags on the question, it is obvious OP should be able to find it, but from the question itself, it does not really seem like he knows about it.

Comment: I am AWARE but not FAMILIAR with `priority queue`. I am trying to determine if this is indeed the correct tool for the job and whether there is a better / different / recommended approach to this problem using existing tools or libraries that have already taken care or the pitfalls.

Comment: Also as I see it `PriorityQueue` requires me to use `PriorityQueue.poll()` to get the head of the queue. This isn't ideal as it requires another process to poll. Ideally once the task is in the queue, the queue prioritises and passes the task to its handler.

Comment: Now you specified how much you want to have done by said library, see edit. It should be sufficient for your use.

Comment: @tarka - A queue is a data structure.  It doesn't **do** anything - a thread or process has to act on the queue, and that's what the thread that calls `PriorityQueue.poll()` is for.

Comment: Based on all your comments I have written an implementation using `PriorityBlockingQueue`. Before adding it to this question I want to make sure the code is sound so I have posted a _code review_ [here](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92339/priority-blocking-queue-implementation).

Comment: @tarka In my opinion is your solution overengineered and you have been already presented with solution that java contains out of the box. I added simple example code which has pretty much the same use as what you have shown, so please, take a look at that. I do not know whether there is some functionality you have been expecting out of that system, but it is quite flexible. I understand you will want to use your code, assuming it currently works, but I'd strongly advise against it, as it brings unnecessary complexity.

Comment: @Vojtěch Kaiser I really like your solution. However, your example requires that an `EventWrapper` be added to `executor` from the `main()` class. Once I have exited the `main()` I can no longer gain access to the instantiated `executor`. This leads me back to a `singleton` approach. I need to be able to add `EventWrapper` from __anywhere__ at __any time__ to the same queue.

Comment: @Vojtěch Kaiser I'm actually going to mark this as the best answer as it is considerably more elegant than my solution. However, it should be noted that for my implementation I still needed to place the `ThreadPoolExecutor` in a `singleton`.

Answer (score 0):

If you are already familiar with [`PriorityBlockingQueue`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/PriorityBlockingQueue.html), why don't you simply poll it to handle hardware requests?

```
public class HardwareHandler

    public static final PriorityBlockingQueue<Message> queue = 
        new PriorityBlockingQueue<Message>();

    static {
        while (true) {
            Message m = queue.take();
            handleMessage(m);
        }
    }

    private static void handleMessage(Message m) {
        // handle message....
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Following all the helpful comments and answers I determined that there probably isn't a pre-built solution for this. In order to try and provide a comprehensive answer to the question I have had a go at writing my own implementation using a `PriorityBlockingQueue`.

I posted the code on [StackExchange Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/), you can see the full code and any community suggested improvements.

[**See answer on code review**](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/92339/priority-blocking-queue-implementation)